# How to print index in integers from DataFrame Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames (1) fruit, and (2) market. Both have three rows denoted 0,1,2 and only one column with no header.

```
print fruit
0   apple
1   pear
2   melon

print market
0   apple
1   pear
2   melon
```

I would like to to print the index in integers and tried below but have hard time in

```
print market.iloc[np.where(fruit[0] == market)].index
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')

print market.iloc[np.where(fruit[0] == market)].index.tolist
<bound method Int64Index.tolist of Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')>

print market.iloc[np.where(fruit[0] == market)].index.values
[0]

print market.iloc[np.where(fruit[0] == market)].index.get_values
<bound method Int64Index.get_values of Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')>
```

What should I do to print 0 only without the brackets?
Goal:
0

Comment: Err, what do you want to do really? These look like series to me.

Comment: typo `nosec_db.iloc[np.where(nosec_tmplt[0] == nosec_db)].index.tolist()`

Comment: What I as trying to do is: find out which index of market is matching fruit[0] hence apple. And then print that index as an integer, not a list. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. found the answer. Was a very simple one. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: print int(market.iloc[np.where(fruit[0] == market)].index.values)
    0

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
print(list(market.index)[0])
print(list(fruit.index)[0])
```

Comment: Hi unfortunately no. I do want the condition to find the index from market which matches fruit[0]. Thanks for the input though.